# WinForms: object data source usage best practice

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding

I want to bind list of business objects to Winforms control (DataGridview, ComboBox, e.t.c.).

There are several approaches to do that:

I can create wrapper classes for business objects and override their `ToString` method implementation. That will work nice for ComboBox, ListBox  `Items.(Add|AddRange)` methods.

But this will not work for DataGridView. It requires ObjectDataSource to tune columns in a designer mode.

As there should be ObjectDataSources (for DataGridViews) and wrapper classes I decided to leave only one approach. The ObjectDataSource one.

Now I have ObjectDataSources for databinding. When I use wizard it adds property to a form that I can use like the following:

```
MyObjectDataSoure.DataSource = list-of-entities;
```

That populates underlying winforms control. But I can also assign list of entities directly to datasource property of control and population will be the same.

```
 MyWinformsControl.DataSource = list-of-entities
```

Yes, now I am without ObjectDataSource events, but may be there is something more general I miss? Should I avoid listening to winforms events (selection changed, user adding a row) and use object data source ones?

What is the best practice to use object datasources and it's events ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5):

First of all, do not bind a Window Forms form or control directly to your data objects.  There are several known bugs (e.g.: [https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/92260/datagrid-memory-leak-resulted-from-failed-clear-of-databind](https://web.archive.org/web/20101011072509/https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/92260/datagrid-memory-leak-resulted-from-failed-clear-of-databind)) involving a failure of the Windows Forms binding mechanism to properly release objects under direct binding.  Instead, always bind via a BindingSource, which will allow your objects to be released for garbage collection if they are not in use elsewhere.

As for the rest, I would recommend keeping the binding mechanism as simple as you can overall.  If you need to add object data sources for some particular circumstances such as the DataGridView design-time support, do so only for those cases.  One of these days, you might end up using an alternate grid control that does not have a similar limitation, and it would be mighty inconvenient to be stuck with an overly complex overall binding pattern just because of a problem that you don't even have anymore.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Nicole. I played with binding source and have a question: is there "beforeDelete" event? I can handle only "afterDelete". It looks like binding sources provide week abilities to handle winControl -> underlying data source communication. I would like to have monolithic approach how to handle events but it looks like bindingSources are not enough. If i use DataGrid + listBox I can handle delete events on bindingSource for dataGrid but would have to listen "keyDowns" on listBox.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think I understand what you mean by that last comment.  A BindingSource serves as a relatively transparent intermediate layer between your actual data source and the bindings of a control or controls.  Besides targeting it at binding time, you shouldn't need to interact with it at all.  You should be able to continue to perform deletions exactly as you are already doing.